# Best way to know how to determine if it is a folder or a file

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory

I am looking for the best approach on how to determine if it's a file or a folder type.
My Main motive here is to count the folders but I have a situation that my folder can be named such as test.ok and code should count this also , as long it is a folder my counter should increment.

Any Ideas about this?

Comment: Please define what you mean with "it" in "if it's a file or a folder type". What is your input? A full path? A SplFileInfo object? Just a file name?

Comment: A fullpath ex: is_dir('localhost/assets/vol/kon/1010.processed/'); how come it returns me a false value?

Comment: this is not a path on your filesystem, **except** if you have a directory like `/var/www/localhost/assets/vol/kon/10.10.processed` (or on windows like `c:\htdocs\localhost\assets\vol\kon\10.10.processed`)

Comment: @fab I already tried using is_dir('C:/wamp/www/assets/vol/ftp2/kontor/2012111315354250618724249.processed') but still it gives me a false value.

Comment: Then what does `is_readable()` and `file_exists()` give you?

Comment: @fab , both function returns me a false value also. What does it mean?

Comment: Have a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php): Does PHP have read permissions on the file/folder? Is it a symlink? Is it a file >2 GB? Is PHP running in safe_mode? Or maybe it just does not exist...

Comment: the permission is readable, it's not sylink , filesize is 1gb+ , the file exist also.

Comment: @drixsonosena where is this script located? `localhost` or in some other folder?

Comment: @class the script is in the localhost

Comment: @drixsonosena have you have tried this: `is_dir('assets/vol/kon/10.10.processed');` because localhost is part of the URI.

Answer (score 5):

[is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) seems to be the PHP command you are looking for: Tells whether the given filename is a directory.

Comment: Hi , I already used this two methods but it keeps returning me false. ex. is_dir('localhost/assets/vol/kon/1010.processed/'); this is a false it should be true coz the path i gave is directory.

Comment: @drixsonosena "localhost/..." isn't a path, it's a URI. You need to use the actual OS path relative to your root index.php file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say use this to check directory/file

```
if(is_file($file))#File
if(is_dir($file))#directory/folder
```

**EDIT** as per your comment you might want to try `echo filetype($file)`

Comment: Hi , I already used this two methods but it keeps returning me false.

ex. is_dir('localhost/assets/vol/kon/1010.processed/'); this is a false it should be true coz the path i gave is directory.

Comment: @drixsonosena what are you entering into as `$file`

Comment: @drixsonosena I would check first that the file exists using `file_exists`.

Comment: @drixsonosena where is your php script located, because you might need to use something like '../dir_structure'

Comment: @jim , there's no problem with the permission.

Comment: @drixsonosena what does your directory structure look like. Try doing `is_dir('assets/vol/kon/10.10.processed');` also you may need to have this in the root dir of `localhost`

Comment: I even tried this two approach : is_dir('C:/wamp/www/assets/vol/ftp2/kontor/00000000000001298371893799.processed'); and is_dir('localhost/assets/vol/ftp2/kontor/00000000000001298371893799.processed'); but both of them gives false value

Comment: @drixsonosena try removing localhost